# Installed OhMyZsh but its loading Bash

Tags: osx-yosemite, iterm

I have just installed OhMyZsh, all was working fine until I decided to open a new tab. It showed up using Bash instead of OhMyZsh and now OhMyZsh isnt loading anymore, even if I quit iTerm and open a new one. How can I fix it?

This is my setup: Yosemite + iTerm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two choices:

1) Change the user login default shell to zsh:

```
chsh -s /bin/zsh
```

See the man page for details:

```
man chsh
```

2) Keep the login default shell, but assign zsh to one of your iTerm's profile (assuming you want to do that to the default profile)

Open `iTerm Preferences`

Select your default profile (the star'd one)

Go to `General` tab (property page)

In the `Command` section, change the selection from `Login Shell` to `Command`

Type/Assign `zsh` in the `Command` field.

Any time you create a new iTerm shell using this profile, you will get zsh instead of your login shell (i.e. bash). You can have create multiple profiles and assign zsh, bash, etc... to the `Command`..., your choice.